# Keep script position in terminal

Tags: powershell, tui

I want to write a Powershell script that shows a few lines (maybe 5), but they stay in the same spot/position in the terminal window. For example: If I was writing a script that printed if a few devices were pingable, I wouldn't want the output to keep scrolling down the terminal; I would want each line to stay in the position they are in, but update over time.

Ex:

```
+----------------------+    +----------------------+
|       TERMINAL       |    |       TERMINAL       |
+----------------------+    +----------------------+
| Device1: PINGABLE    |    | Device1: NOT PINGABLE|
| Device2: NOT PINGABLE|    | Device2: NOT PINGABLE|
|                      |    |                      |
|                      |    |                      |
|                      |    |                      |
|                      |    |                      |
+----------------------+    +----------------------+
```

The script continues to run, the lines stay in the same place, and the output updates if necessary. How could I implement this in Powershell?

I just found this forum post that outlines my question more clearly:
http://www.minasi.com/forum/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=29171

Is this still the case? Is it still not possible?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at `$host.UI.RawUI` and specifically `$host.UI.RawUI.SetBufferContents(...)`.

Comment: I'm having trouble finding info on that, but I'll keep looking (I have a couple books). Theoretically with this, could I have a line of output that is displayed in the powershell window, and if some aspect of it changes, the color of the output changes?

Comment: I found a forum post that asks the same question I am, but in a different way, but it looks like it couldn't be done. Has this changed?    http://www.minasi.com/forum/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=29171

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is possible because the original PowerTab script from MoW displays an ASCII art list box to show multiple matches that you tab through.  See http://thepowershellguy.com/blogs/posh/archive/2007/10/28/powertab-version-0-99-beta-2-released.aspx