# Real-time console screen

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to take a list of servers, execute a "ForEach" command to ping and respond to the console window, displaying all servers in $x number of columns, overwriting their servername?  I was think of displaying their name in green if server is up, and changing to red if it's down.

What I got so far:

```
$ServerL = "filename.txt"
$ScreenD = "ScreenDisplay.ps1"

while ($true) {
    if(Test-Path $ScreenD) { 
        Remove-item $ScreenD
    }

    function GetStatusCode {
        param([int] $StatusCode)

        switch($StatusCode) {
            0 {"Success"}
            11001{"Buffer Too Small"}
            11002{"Destination Net Unreachable"}
            11003 {"Destination Host Unreachable"}
            11004 {"Destination Protocol Unreachable"}
            11005 {"Destination Port Unreachable"}
            11006 {"No Resources"}
            11007 {"Bad Option"}
            11008 {"Hardware Error"}
            11009 {"Packet Too Big"}
            11010 {"Request Timed Out"}
            11011 {"Bad Request"}
            11012 {"Bad Route"}
            11013 {"TimeToLive Expired Transit"}
            11014 {"TimeToLive Expired Reassembly"}
            11015 {"Parameter Problem"}
            11016 {"Source Quench"}
            11017 {"Option Too Big"}
            11018 {"Bad Destination"}
            11032 {"Negotiating IPSEC"}
            11050 {"General Failure"}
            default {"Failed"}
        }
    }

    Write-Host "`n"

    foreach($Server In Gc $ServerList) {

        $PingStatus = Gwmi Win32_PingStatus -Filter "Address ='$Server'" | Select-Object StatusCode

        if ($PingStatus.StatusCode -eq 0) {    
            Add-Content ($filename) "write-host $Server is up -foreground green"
        }    
        else {    
            Add-Content ($filename) "write-host $Server is up -foreground red"
        }    
    }

    ./screendisplay.ps1 | Format-Wide {$_} -Column 4 -Force

    # Gc $filename  | Format-Wide {$_} -Column 4 -Force

    Write-Host "`n"    

    Sleep -seconds (2)    
}
```

Comment: Are you having a problem with it?  A specific error?

Comment: maybe you want to check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13572705/keep-script-position-in-terminal